# Arbitrary named counter, referenced

Tags: cross-referencing, counters

Apologies if this has been asked before, but I simply can't find it, despite voluminous searching. Some question answer bits of my question, but not the whole. The problem is this. I want a counter which is effectively non-numeric, with arbitrary (text) names, which can be referenced. E.g., in a table:

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Project-Quick  \label{quick} & [Details here.] \\
Task-Brown     \label{brown} & [Details here.] \\ 
Todo-Fox       \label{fox}   & [Details here.] \\
Project-Jumped \label{jump}  & [Details here.] \\
\end{tabular}
```

Where: "\ref{jump} has been completed.", would produce the output: "Project-Jumped has been completed."

Is this possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `\label` macro cannot know what you are tagging unless you mark the relevant text somehow. For example `\section` tags the section number as something that `\label` can name.

Here I setup a new reference system for projects so that you can tag things with `\project` and optionally tag them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{My notes for Bla}
\author{myself}

\newcommand{\projectnamestyle}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\newcommand{\projectnamerefstyle}[1]{[\textsc{#1}]}
\newcounter{project}

    \newcommand{\project}[1]{%
      \projectnamestyle{#1}%
       \renewcommand{\theproject}{\projectnamerefstyle{#1}}%
       \refstepcounter{project}%
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \project{Project-Quick}  \label{quick} & [Details here.] \\
  \project{Task-Brown}     \label{brown} & [Details here.] \\
  \project{Todo-Fox}       \label{fox}   & [Details here.] \\
  \project{Project-Jumped} \label{jump}  & [Details here.] \\
\end{tabular}

And \ref{jump} has been completed.
\end{document}
```

You can customize (or remove) `\projectnamestyle` to set the appearances of project names.
You can similarly change how references to project names are typeset by changing the definition of `\projectnamerefstyle` (here it surrounds the reference by square brackets just for illustration).

The key here is calling `\refstepcounter{YOURCOUNTER}` that makes the next `\label` to pick up whatever is "stored" in `\theYOURCOUNTER`.

### Update thanks to @egreg

The previous solution is correct but makes use of a counter which in this case is not necessary since the reference does not require automatic numbering.

A more succinct solution is to define

```
\newcommand{\projectnamestyle}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\newcommand{\projectnamerefstyle}[1]{[\textsc{#1}]}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\project}[1]{%
  \projectnamestyle{#1}%
  \def\@currentlabel{\projectnamerefstyle{#1}}%
}
\makeatother
```

since redefining `\@currentlabel` is the only effect of `\refstepcounter` that we were actually using.

Comment: You could simply do `\def\@currentlabel{\projectnamerefstyle{#1}}`, without using a counter and redefining `\theproject`, because `\label` picks up whatever is the current expansion of `\@currentlabel`.

Comment: @egreg interesting. I guess this is still useful if the OP wants to switch to some automatic counting in the future.

Comment: Almost there I think. In trying out the more succinct version, I get "! LaTeX Error: \theproject undefined.". In trying out the version with a counter, it works perfectly, but encloses the referred project in square brackets, which I'd like to be rid of.

Comment: Remember `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`!

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you put `\renewcommand{\theproject}{\projectnamerefstyle{#1}}` inside the definition of `\project`? Seems unnecessary to me...

Comment: @cgnieder if outside, you only have access to the `project` counter, how do you get the needed `#1`? ah, you mean in the second approach without counter. Well, yes, then there is no need whatsoever for a `\theproject` (as mentioned by `egreg` already)

Comment: @DrRaveemIsmail to get rid of the square brackets just redefine `\newcommand{\projectnamerefstyle}[1]{\textsc{#1}}` or whatever. You can also get rid of `\projectnamestyle` and `\projectnamerefstyle` completely, I just put them there as a generalisation...

Comment: @cgnieder yes that was a leftover from copy&paste =)

Comment: Sometimes you learn more by answering than by asking =D this community is great!

Comment: Oh, I see... I misread the code... my bad :)

Comment: Fantastic. Both work, in exactly the ways that they should, and are extensible for future use. Problem solved.