# Hyperref: how to correctly redefine `\@currentlabel`?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I am using [my own solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179264/36686) to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/179261/36686) to create custom cross-references.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{My notes for Bla}
\author{myself}

\newcommand{\thingnamestyle}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\newcommand{\thingnamerefstyle}[1]{[\textsc{#1}]}
% This works, but is unnecessarily complicated
% \newcounter{thing}
%     \newcommand{\thing}[1]{%
%       \thingnamestyle{#1}%
%        \renewcommand{\thething}{\thingnamerefstyle{#1}}%
%        \refstepcounter{thing}%
%     }
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\thing}[1]{%
  \thingnamestyle{#1}%
  \def\@currentlabel{\thingnamerefstyle{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Bla}
\lipsum[1]
  \thing{thing-Quick} \label{quick}
\lipsum[1]
  \thing{Task-Brown}  \label{brown}
\lipsum[1]
And \ref{quick} has been completed.
\end{document}
```

This works but `hyperref` inserts the wrong link in the `\ref`: clicking on it would jump to the section title, which, I suppose, is the last thing that sets `\@currentlable` other than my `\thing` macro.

If one defines `\thing` using ref counters as in the commented code above, the link seems to work properly.

**What's missing to make `\thing` compatible with `hyperref`?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to yield an appropriate hyperlink, issue `\phantomsection` at the end of `\thing`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\thing}[1]{%
  \thingnamestyle{#1}%
  \def\@currentlabel{\thingnamerefstyle{#1}}%
  \phantomsection%
}
\makeatother
```

Note that if `\thingnamerefstyle` is expanded what written to the `.aux` file. It is sometimes more customary to `\protect` this:

```
  ...
  \def\@currentlabel{\protect\thingnamerefstyle{#1}}$
  ...
```

Comment: Excellent! The `\protect` comment is also helpful.

Comment: The name `\phantomsection` is not very suggestive of its effect though. Could you expand a little on its meaning?

Comment: @Bordaigorl: Fundamentally documents are broken into compartments, or sectional units. These sectional units represent the only points of reference and are typically marked using `\section`. As such, since hyperlinks could be used for things other than jumps to sectional units, the author decided to create a "phantom section" to mark these locations. Look at the code for `\phantomsection` and you'll see that it's just an abbreviation for setting an appropriately-raised (to avoid jumping to the baseline of where it's called) hyperlink anchor.