Custom list using enumitem leads to incorrect referencing
Problem
After my waltzing around in enumitem land, I've run into another issue: referencing items from my custom list.
If I write a few items in my custom list, and I reference them (using the usual \label{...} and \ref{...}), it:

works correctly only when the \label{...} is set on \item command without an optional argument supplied;
produces no reference (and therefore link when using hyperref) if \label{...} (current label) is set on an \item[...] (an \item command with an optional argument supplied) iff no \label{...} was previously set on an \item with an optional argument supplied (before the current \label{...}).
produces the wrong output and references (and links to, when using hyperref) the previous correctly set reference if \label{...} (current label) is set on an \item[...] (an \item with an optional argument supplied) iff \label{...} was previously set on an \item without an optional argument supplied (before the current \label{...}).

I have a hunch that it's because the reference target or counter or label (or something internal) isn't being updated when using the custom formatting, but I really don't know where I would go looking for such a thing... OR I could be completely wrong here, who knows?
MWE
Code
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newlist{axioms}{enumerate}{1}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\customlistformatting}{m m m}{% label text, counter name, \@itemlabel default
  % #1 = argument supplied (\@itemlabel if no argument supplied)
  \ifx\@itemlabel #3
    % #2 counter automatically stepped if no argument is supplied
    \unskip{\bfseries #1~\arabic{#2}}%
  \else
    \stepcounter{#2}% Manually step #2 when argument supplied
    \unskip{\bfseries #1~\arabic{#2}}~({\itshape #3}).%
  \fi
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\csname p@#2\endcsname\arabic{#2}}% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/380524
  \phantomsection% I've tried this, but to no avail (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198853)
}
\makeatother

\setlist[axioms,1]{
    ref={axiom \arabic*},
    align=left,
    format=\customlistformatting{Axiom}{axiomsi},
    itemindent=0.5\leftmargin,
}



\title{\TeX{}.SE MWE}
\author{BrightBulb123}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{axioms}
    \item[ABC Law]  \label{ax:someStarterAxiom}     If 1\dots
    \item           \label{ax:someAxiom}            If 2\dots
    \item[DEF Law]  \label{ax:someOtherAxiom}       If 3\dots
    \item           \label{ax:someOtherAxiomToo}    If 4\dots
\end{axioms}

This is a reference to \ref{ax:someStarterAxiom}.  % Should display: "axiom 1", which it doesn't. It just displays it as an empty reference/link.

This is a reference to \ref{ax:someAxiom}.  % Should display: "axiom 2", which it does.

This is a reference to \ref{ax:someOtherAxiom}.  % Should display: "axiom 3", which it doesn't. It just points to the old one ("axiom 2").

This is a reference to \ref{ax:someOtherAxiomToo}.  % Should display: "axiom 4", which it does.

\end{document}

Error
Package hyperref Warning: Suppressing empty link on input line 46.

Image


P.S. The custom function is trying to be generic because I want to create a few custom lists, for example, axioms, caseslist, etc. :)

@ BrighttBulb I think the answer by egreg is a much cleaner solution, I recommend changing the accepted answer from mine to his.

@Marijn the reason I accepted your answer as opposed to @egreg's answer is because while egreg's is a lot cleaner and nicer to maintain, I prefer (out of vanity or foolishness, whichever applies) an answer which deals with the mangly bits in the preamble so I don't need to change the actual way I use my lists (e.g., I can continue to use \item instead of \axiom, etc.). egreg's answer is very helpful for others who may not impose this restriction on themselves, which is why I have upvoted it too.

You set \@currentlabel within the formatting function, so it has local scope. Therefore it is unset when the formatting is done. You can set it to global scope with xdef (global expanded) instead of edef (local expanded).
Moreover I'm not sure what p@#2 is supposed to do but it doesn't print the word axiom. Fortunately the word axiom is given in #1 so you can lower case it.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newlist{axioms}{enumerate}{1}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\customlistformatting}{m m m}{% label text, counter name, \@itemlabel default
  % #1 = argument supplied (\@itemlabel if no argument supplied)
  \ifx\@itemlabel #3
    % #2 counter automatically stepped if no argument is supplied
    \unskip{\bfseries #1~\arabic{#2}}%
  \else
    \stepcounter{#2}% Manually step #2 when argument supplied
    \unskip{\bfseries #1~\arabic{#2}}~({\itshape #3}).%
  \fi
  \protected@xdef\@currentlabel{\lowercase{#1} \arabic{#2}}% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/380524
  \phantomsection% I've tried this, but to no avail (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/198853)
}
\makeatother

\setlist[axioms,1]{
    ref={axiom \arabic*},
    align=left,
    format=\customlistformatting{Axiom}{axiomsi},
    itemindent=0.5\leftmargin,
}



\title{\TeX{}.SE MWE}
\author{BrightBulb123}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{axioms}
    \item[ABC Law]  \label{ax:someStarterAxiom}     If 1\dots
    \item           \label{ax:someAxiom}            If 2\dots
    \item[DEF Law]  \label{ax:someOtherAxiom}       If 3\dots
    \item           \label{ax:someOtherAxiomToo}    If 4\dots
\end{axioms}

This is a reference to \ref{ax:someStarterAxiom}.  % Should display: "axiom 1", which it doesn't. It just displays it as an empty reference/link.

This is a reference to \ref{ax:someAxiom}.  % Should display: "axiom 2", which it does.

This is a reference to \ref{ax:someOtherAxiom}.  % Should display: "axiom 3", which it doesn't. It just points to the old one ("axiom 2").

This is a reference to \ref{ax:someOtherAxiomToo}.  % Should display: "axiom 4", which it does.

\end{document}

Result:


globally setting @currentlabel{ might have some rather unexpected (or expected) global effects, it would be better to just lift it out of one layer of grouping

@David that sounds like a good idea, however where would you put it then? It still needs to be connected to \item[opt] because that disables the counter increment of \item. Or is there some kind of gdef that goes only one level up?

I agree with David, you shouldn't set @currentlabel globally.

there are ways to lift a value out of a group (pgf has a whole smuggle setup for that) but for example \def\foo{aaa}  \edef\tmp{\egroup\def\noexpand\foo{\foo}}\tmp  ends a group and locally defines \foo outside the group to the value it had inside

@DavidCarlisle I've tried to implement your suggestion like the following: ... \protected@edef\@currentlabel{\lowercase{#1} \arabic{#2}} \edef\@tmp{\egroup\def\noexpand\@currentlabel{\@currentlabel}}% \@tmp ..., but this doesn't work... any suggestions on how this could be accomplished?

I'd do it differently, using a specific command instead of \item.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newlist{axioms}{enumerate}{1}

\newif\ifaxiomname
\NewDocumentCommand{\axiom}{o}{%
  \axiomnamefalse
  \IfValueT{#1}{\axiomnametrue\def\axiomname{#1}}%
  \item
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\maybeaxiomname}{}{%
  \ifaxiomname\ (\textit{\axiomname})\fi
}

\setlist[axioms,1]{
  label=\textbf{Axiom \arabic*}\maybeaxiomname,
  ref={axiom \arabic*},
  wide,
}



\title{\TeX{}.SE MWE}
\author{BrightBulb123}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{axioms}
  \axiom[ABC Law]  \label{ax:someStarterAxiom}     If 1\dots 
  \axiom           \label{ax:someAxiom}            If 2\dots 
  \axiom[DEF Law]  \label{ax:someOtherAxiom}       If 3\dots 
  \axiom           \label{ax:someOtherAxiomToo}    If 4\dots 
\end{axioms}

This is a reference to \ref{ax:someStarterAxiom} (should display: `axiom 1')

This is a reference to \ref{ax:someAxiom} (should display: `axiom 2')

This is a reference to \ref{ax:someOtherAxiom} (should display: `axiom 3')

This is a reference to \ref{ax:someOtherAxiomToo} (should display: `axiom 4')

\end{document}


